# How to add multiple text watermark over an image using Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to implement an app in flutter which will add multiple text watermark over the image. But using my code I am not getting exact result

Here is my code I have written

`main.dart` file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:test_app1/watarmark.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);


  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  

  @override
  initState() {

    super.initState();


  }

  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Card(
          child: Container(
            // width: double.infinity,
            height: 250,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/images/image.jpg'),
                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              ),
            ),
            child: Watarmark(
              rowCount: 3,
              columnCount: 9,
              text: "My DigiShell",
            ),
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      
    );
  }
}
```

And the `watermark.dart` page is as below

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Watarmark extends StatelessWidget {
  final int rowCount;
  final int columnCount;
  final String text;

  const Watarmark(
      {Key key,
        @required this.rowCount,
        @required this.columnCount,
        @required this.text})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IgnorePointer(
      child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: creatColumnWidgets(),
          )),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> creatRowWdiges() {
    List<Widget> list = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
      final widget = Expanded(
          child: Center(
              child: Transform.rotate(
                angle: - pi / 10,
                child: Text(
                  text,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.blue, // Color(0x08000000),
                      fontSize: 14,
                      decoration: TextDecoration.none),
                ),
              )));
      list.add(widget);
    }
    return list;
  }

  List<Widget> creatColumnWidgets() {
    List<Widget> list = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
      final widget = Expanded(
          child: Row(
            children: creatRowWdiges(),
          ));
      list.add(widget);
    }
    return list;
  }
}
```

Using the code I am getting the output like this

[image]

In the picture text is being overflowed from the image. I want the text just on the image only.

First I was trying to implement using `Stack` it was also overflowing, it was not clipped.

I will share the watermarked image taking a screenshot dynamically only on a widget

Here is the output of using stack

[image]

Comment: Please add the plugins you are using as there are multiple ones on the pub dev directory.

Comment: Your code is full of errors and does not run on newest Flutter SDK.
Could you specify your SDK version you are using?

I can't even launch your project without editing it.

Comment: @petrasJ I didnt use any plugins for this purpose, The only plugin you can see is flutter window manager is just for testing purpose to prevent screenshot or screen recording. that has no use on this

Comment: Thats still a plugin which other people will have to find themselves

Comment: @petrasJ Its flutter 2.2.3

Comment: Flutter 2.2.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision f4abaa0735 (2 weeks ago) • 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
Engine • revision 241c87ad80
Tools • Dart 2.13.4  //   android min sdk api level 25 target 30

Comment: @petras Now you can check I have removes extra codes

Comment: Still 6 errors.

Comment: @petras hehe, I cant see any errors

Comment: @petrasJ I have solved using a future function The errors you are getting it may be for null safety, I have also faced some error when tried to create a new project for this